# Django rest-framework: Spring Boot like model serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am looking forward to build a "mother of REST" rest api with the django REST framework. Therefore I like to have all relationships represented as urls. Using Spring Boot this is pretty easy, but not so for django REST I think. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I have to models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='groups', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    shared_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='shared_groups')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Now I like the model relation ships to be serialized like the following schema (for shortness I only show the User model as json):

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "username":"user_1",
   "email":"user_1@test.de",
   "created_at":"2019-03-08T08:42:34.766951Z",
   "_links":{  
      "self":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1/",
      "groups":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/1/groups"
   }
}
```

I know I can get the `self` url by passing it to the `fields`, but I like to have it in the `_links` section. I tried using the `serializers.SerializerMethodField`to add the extra information. But I have no idea to generate the urls for representing the objects.

Can anyone help?

By the way the serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    _links = serializers.SerializerMethodField('representations')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'created_at', 'password', '_links')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
            'groups': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    def representations(self, obj):
        _links = dict()
        _links['self'] = 'link to user'
        _links['groups'] = 'hers should be the link to the groups'

        return _links
```

Comment: Try having your SerializerMethodField return a dict containing HyperlinkedRelatedFields. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield

Comment: Yes i tried this and it work. But that is not nice. I just moved back to Spring, the resource representation is much easier.